# @Autowired интерфейса без реализации в сервисе

Tags: java, spring

Есть некий интерфейс:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    @Annotation1
    @Annotation2
    @Annotation3
    String getSomeNewObject(Object obj);
}
```

В нём благодаря аннотациями уже описана вся логика и нет нужды в реализации сервиса. Как можно сделать `@Autowired` этого интерфейса и вызывать его в другом сервисе например.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    SomeInterface someInterface;

    public String doSomething(Object obj) {
        String str = someInterface.getSomeNewObject(obj);
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить и идти по накатанной программистами дороге, то ответ такой:

> Нет. Это невозможно, `Spring` попытается найти и создать экземпляр с реализацией
>   (`Instance`) данного интерфейса, а как нам известно создавать
>   экземпляры интерфейса или абстрактных классов нельзя.

Но если сойти с ума, то конечно возможно всё, однако данный способ очень нетривиальный и скорее всего если ваш код будет сопровождать психопат знающий где вы живёте, будет не очень приятно.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeBeanConfig {
  @Bean
  public SomeInterface publicBean() {
    return new SomeInterface() {
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте пустую реализацию ващего интерфейса, поставьте над ней @Component, и инжектайте себе спокойно, так как и хотели, через @Autowired